# The view with UNION is failing to return the result of the first part of the query when the dblink fails

Tags: sql, oracle, union, dblink

I have one `view` containing two tables with the same information. The only difference is that the first one is a subset of the second one.
The first `table` named **SMALL_TABLE** with *1-month* of data to allow various queries to run quicker and another `table` named **BIG_TABLE** with more than *6 months* of data in another database.
I use a `db_link` in the view from the DB where the small table is located to join both tables with `UNION` operator to return any results where the date range is greater than one month.
This has worked perfectly so far. But the issue is that when the second DB is not available, the view as well fails to return even these data from the first table. How can I still get results from the first part of the view for specific queries with a date range of less than one month despite the unavailability of the second DB for certain reasons?

```
SELECT COL1 DATEFIELD1, COL2 ALIASFIELD2, COL3 ALIASFIELD3
FROM SMALL_TABLE
WHERE DATEFIELD < TRUNC(SYSDATE)-31
UNION
SELECT COL1 DATEFIELD1, COL2 ALIASFIELD2, COL3 ALIASFIELD3
FROM BIG_TABLE@DBLINK_MAINDB
WHERE DATEFIELD >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-31
```

Comment: There is no mechanism to allow the results of the first query to return even if the table in the second query can't be reached. You could have a routine that attempts to call the view, and if that fails, then call the `SMALL_TABLE` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have an idea on how it could be done? I was thinking about a `PL/SQL` procedure that could handle this as an exception...

Comment: Reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm for guidance on catching the exception and handling it. If you can't trap for that situation with  a existing exception, you'll have to do a little defensive coding to determine if the table is available first by checking out `V$DBLINK` or another metadata table - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin005.htm#ADMIN12175

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I'll have a look and let you know my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from a view to a **materialized view** could be one option. Unlike an "ordinary" view, which is just a stored query and doesn't contain any data itself, a materialized view actually *contains* data and acts as if it was a *table*; for example, you can create indexes on it.

Benefit is that - even if database link is *down* for some reason, materialized view will still hold data and let you perform queries.

How does it get refreshed? It depends on you; schedule it to e.g. at 02:00 when nobody is working and it'll be ready in the morning. Or, do it twice a day. Or, refresh it on demand (you'd explicitly perform refresh). Or, do it when commit happens in underlying table(s). Those options are described in documentation; once you figure out *which one* to use, see *how* to enforce it.

Furthermore, materialized view would select **only** from the `BIG_TABLE` (as it contains all data; you said that `SMALL_TABLE` is its subset) and you'd avoid `UNION` which can be expensive as it eliminates duplicate rows.

In its simplest way, you'd

```
create materialized view mv_big_table as
select col1 datefield1,
       col2 aliasfield2,
       col3 aliasfield3
from big_table@dblink_maindb;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While MVs are great objects that can help to implement sophisticate solutions, on the other hand, these objects can badly impact the DB performance degradation. Especially on the UNDO space management due to delete/refresh of the materialized view that caused us many issues - this a personal experience.